# How to use “viewport-fit=cover” and “maximum-scale=1” without disabling zoom on Android

Tags: android, iphone, viewport, meta-tags, pinchzoom

I’ve been using the following viewport `meta` tag on my site:

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, viewport-fit=cover" />
```

On iPhone, this gives me the exact behavior that I want:

- `maximum-scale=1` prevents Safari from zooming in when a text field is focused
- `viewport-fit=cover` removes Safari's left and right padding on the iPhone X in landscape, so the background color and images extend all the way to the edges
- The user can still manually pinch-to-zoom if they want, since iOS always allows it, regardless of any properties in the `meta` tag that would otherwise disable it

But on Android, `maximum-scale=1` and `viewport-fit=cover` prevent zooming entirely, and the only way I’ve found to avoid that is to just remove both properties. But then I lose the benefits of including them on the iPhone as well.

Is there any way I can keep both of these properties in my `meta` tag but *also* still allow manual pinch-to-zoom on Android?

Comment: A better way to prevent Safari from zooming in when a text field is focused is to set `font-size` to a larger value.

Answer (score 0):

You should have been able to achieve what you were looking for by modifying the maximum-scale to something at least above 3.0. Having it as a max of one doesn't allow for any zoom in.

Maximum-scale relates to zoom in and minimum to zoom out from my understanding.